# Calculate date when age plus service equals specific value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use Excel to calculate the date that the sum of an employee's age and years of service equal to 90. This is for the purpose of determining retirement eligibility.

I have two dates - the birth date and hire date. Currently I'm doing the kindergarten version and have two columns, with the age and years of service in months calculating from a date field, that I'm plugging future dates into until the sum equals 1080 (90 yrs).

I'm trying to eliminate the plugging and chugging aspect but I can't wrap my mind around how to incorporate all of this into formula(s).

[image: Sample of the Excel data I am using.]

The formulas I'm using so far:

- `E:E` = Birth Dates
- `F:F` = Hire Dates
- `G2` = I am plugging a potential retirement date into each field in this column and the below formula adds the age and years of service (in months) as of this date. I change the date until the total is greater than or equal to 1080, the lowest number as possible (to determine earliest eligible retirement date).
- `G2 = H2=DATEDIF(E2,G2,"m")+DATEDIF(F2,G2,"m")`
- `G2 = H2=[Age in months + years of service in months]`

Example:

- G2 = E2 = Birth Date = 01-May-1990
- G2 = F2 = Hire Date = 01-Feb-2011
- G2 = G2 = Earliest Retire Date = **01-Oct-2045**
- G2 = H2 = 1081

`01-Sep-2045` equals `1079` months so `01-Oct-2045` is the first month the employee is eligible to retire (earliest date that age + YOS >= 90).  Is there a way to automate this in Excel rather than by trial and error?

Comment: Can you clarify the rules for age and service?  For example, how are months of age at retirement determined?  (e.g., birthday during Jan so any time in Feb = + 1 mo; or birthday is Jan 14 so Feb 14 through Mar 13 = +1 mo; or fractional month is used based on days in each month, or fractional months are used based on 30 days/mo; etc.--usually prescribed by company rules).  Similar question for service months.

Comment: For both age and service you are eligible on the first of the month when age and service will equal 90, and service is counted for the month as long as you work the first day of the month, so service credit for hire dates 2nd-31st begin the following month.  But this calculation is for succession planning purposes so +/- month is okay.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the formula that's in C2 in my sheet as shown, and copied down:

```
=32873-((TODAY()-A2)+(TODAY()-B2))+TODAY()
```

1. Compare `32873`  (90 years of days **)
2. To the sum of two quantities:

`(TODAY()-A2)` days since birth

`(TODAY()-B2)` days since hire

to find how many days remain until eligibility;

3. Divide that number of days by 2, because we want to 'double count' each calendar day between now and eligibility (each day goes toward both age and tenure)
4. add that length of time to `TODAY()` today's date to find the future date of eligibility.

For the record I used about 4-5 columns to put this together, going step by step, until I had the answer that satisfied spec and then combined formulas backwards until I had one overall formula. I didn't actually even have this plan of combining these four values as shown until I had done half the work and was thus able to contain the entire relationship in my mind at one time. I imagine there *are* people that are able to function that way, but I'm not one.

It's a good approach to divide tasks like this into chunks until you can see how they're supposed to work together, if you can't see the whole picture at first.

NOTE I see since you've expanded your question that length of time in months is critical to the calculation. @fixer1234 's questions are necessary here to produce results that are better than almost always right.

** Thank you @fixer1234 for pointing out my mistake - 90 years of days is actually not 32850. A problem is that there are going to be EITHER 22 or 23 leap days added to the calendar in any given 90-year sample between the years 1901 and 2199 CE, depending on whether the period counted starts or ends on a leap year. So, this is a start, but may not be sufficiently precise depending on the exact policies in question.

Comment: I didn't realize until I saw your question what a dumb approach it was for me to just multiply 365 by 90, though of course you're right, and it is. I wouldn't know where to even get started figuring out how to dynamically calculate the number of leap years in a given 90-year sample.

Comment: I get 32872 days for 90 years (if the company rules are based on actual days). Also, assuming 1st day of work and 1st day of life count as 1 day, I think you want to subtract 1 day from each starting date rather than plug TODAY back in as an adjustment (i.e., +2 instead of +TODAY()).

Comment: You could use 365.25 days per year or get fancy with actual leap years.  You could figure out the first leap year after the birth date and go from there.  There are exceptions, like at the turn of most centuries.  A lot of how nuts the formulas need to get is the intended purpose.  The company may have complex rules that apply for the actual qualifying date.  If this is just to estimate within a few days for planning purposes, it might be close enough.

Comment: I think I'm planning on going with 'close enough' - it would be necessary to nest some ifs to determine if either of the two dates included 22 or 23 leap days in the 90-year slice. Given that it sounds like @OP actually needs months of service and not days, thus this is probably the wrong basis for a formula solution anyway, I don't see the margin in continuing down this particular garden path... I thank you for your keen eye to my approach, though.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I've been looking at this spreadsheet for so long today and had just finally thought of a similar way that seems to work, and came back here to check if there were any responses.  I tried =EDATE(TODAY(),((1081-(DATEDIF(E2,TODAY(),"m")+DATEDIF(H2,TODAY(),"m"))))/2).   Regarding months - I really was using months to avoid the leap year calc. The state counts service in whole months anyway so it simplifies it.  thank you all!

Comment: BTW, just noticed that there's no reason for TODAY to be there.  Ignoring units and complex rules, the formula is `Retire - (Birth-1day) + Retire - (Hire-1day) = 90yrs`.  You can get Retire by algebra from that.

Comment: @BagelBiteBiter Sounds like you handled it better than I did, then. I think you should write up the answer, with sample data and screenshot, since we independently arrived at the same method but yours satisfies spec in terms of being written in whole months. Good job!!

Comment: @fixer1234 quite, right, and lovely: =(32873+A2+B2+2)/2